# How to edit/change TTF OS/2 usWeightClass value?

Tags: css, fonts, truetype, woff

I have the [Dosis font](http://www.impallari.com/dosis) which I want to use as a webfont in one of my projects. I can convert the TTF files to WOFF with the [Font Squirrel Webfont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator); nothing new so far. Doing so results in the following error message in the Firefox console:

> downloadable font: OS/2: bad weight: 250 (font-family: "dosis" style:normal weight:200 stretch:normal src index:0) source: http://example.com/fonts/dosis-extralight.woff2

The error message is clear and the problem is clear, but I have no clue how I can change the value from 250 to 200 without altering the font in any other way. I tried with [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/) but the newly generated TTF file is completely different than the original. I also tried to use an HEX editor but couldn't make head or tail of the file's content.

---

Tried it with the “Adobe Font Development Kit for OpenType” and this is the WinMerge DIFF. I can't interpret if this is an issue or not.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with *"FontForge...newly generated TTF file is completely different than the original"*?? Do the font's glyph look different from their original counter parts? Does the font have more or less glyphs?

Comment: I used [ttfdump](http://everythingfonts.com/ttfdump) and WinMerge to compare the output and it was simply completely different. The font looked okay to me, but the fact that the DIFF was so off scared me.

Comment: WinMerge is useless for this. `ttfdump` wants you to *understand* what you are seeing...

Comment: Did `ttfdump -t gsub` list a different number of tables within the font? If yes, which ones were missing?

Comment: It's nice if it wants me to understand and I'd love to understand, but I don't. Tried it with the Adobe tool and included a screenshot of the beginning of the DIFF in my question.

Comment: Ooh... I thought you were a font pro or semi-pro -- after all you've said *"the error message is clear and the problem is clear"*...

Comment: No, not close to that. Never developed a font myself. I always was highly interested in the field and usage increased with the advent of `@font-face` but I'm still a web developer and not a font developer. :)

Comment: Well, the [website for Dosis](http://www.impallari.com/dosis) itself recommends to use the WOFF from Google... But you still wanted to generate the WOFF "with your own hands".

Comment: That (since I'm a curious person who likes to know how things are done) and I honestly didn't know that Google offers font downloads as well. I don't like using their API (privacy, performance, etc.). The download from Google again only provides TTF files, but at least the usWeightClass is set correctly to 200 and not 250.

Comment: Google would violate some free font licenses if they would offer their use only via API, and if they wouldn't offer downloads too...

Comment: Does the tool you used really say "chechsum"? (I guess it does...)

Comment: The tool is called `ttfdump` and was developed by Microsoft. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Check if you have got the `ttx` commandline tool available on your system. If not, follow steps 2-3. If you do, skip to step 4.
2. Check out this Open Source, multi-platform tool from its [Github repository](https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/).
3. Locate the tool `ttx` in the `Tools/osx` or `Tools/linux` or `Tools/win` folder (whichever is appropriate to your OS platform).
4. Type `ttx -h`.
5. Follow the instructions.

In short: Run `ttx -v -o dosis.xml Dosis-Medium.otf`. Edit the generated XML file. Run `ttx dosis.xml -o Dosis-Medium-modified.otf`. Test your Dosis-Medium-modified.otf.

Comment: This works very good, but the `ttfdump` of the newly generated TTF file is again slightly different to the original. I don't know if this is an issue (also see comments on question). Adobe also offers a fully working download at https://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko.html

Comment: I consider this the correct answer, since it allows you to edit the value. The fact that the newly generated TTF file is slightly different is kind of funny, but I can't assess if this would be an issue. I will use the TTF file from Google Fonts as recommended by @ZacWolf and you, since I don't have to worry that I destroyed something through my edits of the font.

Comment: How different is "slightly"? The checksums are recalculated, and possibly the order of TTF tables may differ. In the data for each table nothing ought to change (except where you inserted your own changes).

Answer (score 2):

This already exists as a webfont: http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Dosis

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and I don't want to use Google's Font API.

Comment: Even if you don't want to use the API you can download the font-files themselves...  There is a 200 weight font in the pack.

Comment: Oh, you are right, TTF download with proper usWeightClass. Thanks, removed the down vote as this helps me resolve my initial problem but how can you edit the value yourself?

Comment: Quick search yields: http://www.truetex.com/ttf_edit.htm as a possible way to change the weight value in the OS/2 table.  Apparently the value is a kind of meta-data.

Comment: There's no download available to test the tool you found.